# d3 linear scale - invalid value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I'm super-new to d3 (first time opened this morning). I'm trying to make a linear scale from a csv-data-doc.
First I'm calculating the scale:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, width]);
```

then I'm trying to use it:

```
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(Math.abs(Math.round(d.Betrag))); })
```

however it returns an error "invalid value for  width="NaN"
this one works (basically without the linear scaling:

```
  .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(Math.round(d.Betrag)); })
```

Can someone please help? thanks

Comment: Are you setting a `.domain` for your `x` scale?  What values does `d.Betrag` hold?

Comment: read up on domains. how would I use it with a changing number according to the data? domain(data) doesn't do the trick...
and d.Betrag holds floating point numbers

Comment: `domain` is the limit of your user space coordiantes.  That and `range` map user space to pixel space.  It's usually set as `.domain([minOfData, maxOfData])`, or in your case `.domain(d3.extent(dataArray, function(d){return d.Betrag;}))`.  Regardless, though, the default `domain` of `[0,1]`, should still be working for you.  You'll need to add a reproducible example to your code for me to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

You width variable that you passed to range is probably not a number. Otherwise I can't think of other reason you get NaN as the scale function return.

Answer (score 0):

the answer posted by @Mark in one of the comments above is correct.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.Betrag;}))
  .range([0, width]);
```

or at least almost doing what it's supposed to do... some weirdness going on I noticed now